# Having more than one method in a sidekiq worker class

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sidekiq

I have a sidekiq worker class. I currently implemented it this way. It works when I call PROCESS, and it will queue the method called PERFORM.  But i would like to have more than one method that I can queue.

As a side note, is there a difference doing this and simply doing SocialSharer.delay.perform?

```
# I trigger by using SocialSharer.process("xxx")

class SocialSharer

  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(user_id)
    # does things
  end

  def perform_other_things
    #i do not know how to trigger this
  end

  class << self
    def process(user_id)
      Sidekiq::Client.enqueue(SocialSharer,user_id)
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SocialSharer.delay.perform would delay a class method called perform.  Your perform method is an instance method.

Workers are designed to be one class per job.  The job is started via the perform method.  You can use delay to kick off any number of different class methods on a class, like so:

```
class Foo
  def self.a(count)
  end
  def self.b(name)
  end
end
Foo.delay.a(10)
Foo.delay.b('bob')
```

Comment: Do I still have access to the rails environment from inside the method I call on delay?

Comment: This can be done with the Delayed Job, how to do the same using Sidekiq?

Comment: this is removed from sidekiq 7 and it's no longer possible to use

Answer (score -4):

Well, if you *really* want to have all "performable" methods in one class, I'd suggest you to rename `perform` method to something different (say, `perform_something`), and create a new `perform` method which would *dispatch* the control flow:

```
class SocialSharer
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  # the 3 lines below may be replaced with `alias_method :perform, :public_send`
  def perform(method, *args)
    self.public_send(method, *args)
  end

  def perform_something(user_id)
    # does things
  end

  def perform_other_things
    # does other things
  end

  def self.process(user_id)
    Sidekiq::Client.enqueue(SocialSharer, :perform_something, user_id)
    Sidekiq::Client.enqueue(SocialSharer, :perform_other_things)
  end
end
```